# auto sizing image in div with css works only with width, not height

Tags: css

I'm trying to auto-fit an image to it's container while maintaining its aspect ratio using css. The image has a bit too much height to fit on a phone screen. I'm using this css, which seems like it should work, but it only resizes the image for width changes, not height.

```
body {
    background-color: #0055AF;
    overflow-x: visible;
}

#new_site_teaser {
    width: 405px;
    height: 683px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#new_site_teaser img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7m50rg74/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the #new_site_teaser width to % and define and height and width for the parents (body & html in this case); it'll adjust to each device. It's much better than using pixels. 
See changes: http://jsfiddle.net/7m50rg74/16/

Ensure you have a meta viewport.

add this to your head tag, if not. This defines a viewport for your site to be seen on, in this case it'll adjust the width automatically for every device and have a scale = 1 (zoom).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: That fiddle still doesn't resize for height and now the image isn't centered. I do have the meta viewport.

Comment: i posted your original one by accident, see updated link http://jsfiddle.net/7m50rg74/2/ if this is still wrong. i'll change the answer.

Comment: Still not resizing for height and image still not centered.

Comment: i know what you want now, here you go. just assign a height and width to the body and html tags. http://jsfiddle.net/7m50rg74/13/

Comment: still doesn't preserve the aspect ratio. :)

Comment: I've got it working by just statically resizing the image down 25% with a media query below 638px. Not the ideal solution, but it works.